# “Is on” or “are on”?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is staff plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural)

> - The family *is* on a tour
> - The family *are* on a tour

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: [Possible dupe](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/is-staff-plural).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. The family *is* on a tour
> 2. The family *are* on a tour

Both are correct, as the collective noun *family* can both be treated as singular or plural. However, one is less likely to hear the second sentence in the US, for collective nouns are usually treated as singular in American English, while they can be treated as both singular and plural in British English. See the note on collective noun concord at [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/page/317).

---

You may want also want to consider a related answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/a-total-of-10-babies-is-sleeping-v-s-a-total-of-10-babies-are-sleeping-v-s/8556#8556).