# Singular verb with plural numbers

Tags: grammar

In answer to the question, "Do we need any more chairs?" why does it sound correct to say, "No, three's enough." Why does "three are enough" sound wrong?

Comment: You seem to be asking us to determine why something sounds right or wrong to you. We can only answer from our own perspectives. From mine, either usage sounds fine.

Comment: Duplicate of [Do I use the plural or singular when referring to a positive number less than one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58492/18250)

Comment: Two's company, three's [**is**] a crowd.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [***Use-Mention Problem***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction), and we compound it by talking about it here.

And even more so by **writing** about it and **not** talking.

So we'll have to be very careful about the quotation marks, OK? I'll take it slow.

First, *three* is a word, and it is a plural word, since it denotes a number larger than one. Hence,

- *Is there a doctor around? There **are** three in the next room.*

Second, *three* is a number, and numbers have names.

Third, the ***name*** for the number *three* is **"three"**. ***With*** quotes.

Fourth, the name **"three"** is also a word in English (pronounced just like the number *three*).

Fifth, since it is the name of one thing, the name **"three"** is a singular word. Hence,

- *How much is seven minus four? Three **is** the correct answer*.
- *How many chairs should I put at that table? Six **is** sufficent.*

This last sentence essentially means

- *Six is **[a]** sufficient **[number of chairs]**.*

Therefore, in many situations we have the possibility of referring to any number **either** as a single unit quantity (by referring to the **name** of the number), **or** as a plural set (by referring to the number itself).

Philosophers talk about this as a distinction between ***Using*** a word (that's the plural number *three*), and ***Mentioning*** it (that's the singular name **"three"**), and [they can get quite testy](http://specgram.com/SoLP/17.mccawley.untitled.html) about confusions involving them.

Comment: I'm not convinced this requires a use vs. mention distinction. Amounts generally control singular agreement in English.  See [Do I use the plural or singular when referring to a positive number less than one?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/58492/18250).

Answer (score 1):

Three is singular. There is a single set of three, and that is enough. Or rather, the single number three is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what about "Have the chairs been delivered?" "Fifteen have been delivered, but three are broken." I know it's because a plural noun is implied, but it's no different to the first example. Is it something to do with the word 'enough'?

Comment: @Tom in that case, it appears that "fifteen" is being used with an omitted complement. You are essentially saying "fifteen (chairs) have been delivered".