# “0 Bytes” vs “0 Byte”?

Tags: programming

Just was wondering why and **Which one is the correct one? or both?**

> A zero byte file or zero length file is a computer file containing no
>   data; that is, it has a length or size of zero bytes. Zero byte files
>   cannot be loaded or used by most applications.

*Ref : [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-byte_file)*

**"0 byte"** 741,000 results on Google

**"0 bytes"** 7,470,000 results on Google

Comment: A *zero-byte file* is *zero bytes* in length.

Comment: @choster Ahhh, So this is a programing question ? sorry :(

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. When describing something in units attributively, the singular unit is used (e.g. *forty-degree difference*, *ten-kilometre run*, etc.), as demonstrated in the Wikipedia article you link, and in *[Should we use plural or singular for a fraction of a mile?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2139)*, *[Are units in English singular or plural?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22082)*, or *[“A total of 0.0606 moles of NaOH was” or “were”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58490)* Or was your question about something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct plural form of a noun preceded by "zero"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-noun-preceded-by-zero)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having "zero" before "plurals" does not necessarily mean **zero-quantity**. You  use **zero** but still, talk about an "**abstract collection**".  You may find many examples in English. E.g:

> I do not have any book**s**

Answer (score 0):

The plural is commonly used after "zero" when identifying a quantity of things.  Eg, one might say "There are zero apples in that basket."

As has been suggested in a comment, however, the singular is used when constructing a modifier phrase, as in "We had a zero-apple harvest from that tree."