# Singular or plural verb with "a minimum of"

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, quantifiers

Does the phrase "a minimum of" in conjunction with a plural term require a singular or plural verb?

"*A minimum of 1.6 million reads **was** generated per sample.*"

vs.

"*A minimum of 1.6 million reads **were** generated per sample.*"

**Edit 1:**
I suppose that the situation is similar to using the collective noun "a total of", in which case a plural verb would be required (["A total of 10 babies is..." vs. "a total of 10 babies are..." vs. "Ten babies in total are..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8545/a-total-of-10-babies-is-vs-a-total-of-10-babies-are-vs-ten-babies-i))

Comment: It's not specifically "a minimum" that's being generated per sample, but some number of reads - so it seems logical and correct to use a plural verb.